# Should I make partitions on 500GB SSD or store my projects in C dirve?

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, performance, storage

I have a laptop with 500GB **SSD** (**windows**) and no extra hard disk, there is only one partition on SSD for now which is **C**. Now should I create a new partition for my projects or use **C** drive only?

Comment: Why not just use a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Having all your data on a single drive is insecure no matter how it is partitioned.

If you keep data on a separate partition, then if you need to reinstall the OS, the data is 'safe'. Stored on the same partition, you'd need to do a repair install rather than clean.
This might save some time.

If the drive dies, you've lost everything either way.
Having a solid, tested, up to date backup would mean your data is always safe, no matter what happens to the drive. If I lose a drive here [& I lost three boot drives in a year recently, for unrelated reasons] I can be back up & running within an hour. Maximum data loss, one hour. No reinstall of OS necessary, it was on the backup, along with the data.